# use downloaded request and display on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, ime

So this `URL`translates text: `https://inputtools.google.com/request?text=$&itc=$&num=$\
    &cp=0&cs=1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=test`
and returns
a request file which is downloaded when viewed on browser
by using variables

```
var text = "ca me plait",
    itc = "fr-t-i0-und",
    num = 10;
```

### Result:

```
[
    "SUCCESS",
    [
        [
            "ca me plait",
            [
                "ça me plaît"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can I use this and decode and display result on windows phone?

Comment: Can you share a valid request URL?